TensorFlow CTC Loss: Mismatch Between input_lengths and label_lengths — "Dimensions must be equal" Error
I'm working on an OCR project using TensorFlow, where I aim to train a CRNN (Convolutional Recurrent Neural Network) model to recognize Arabic text from images of ID cards. The model uses CTC Loss (tf.nn.ctc_loss) to handle the alignment between the input image sequence and the target text. However, I encounter the following error during training:
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 62 and 32 for '{{node CTCLoss}} = CTCLoss[T=DT_FLOAT, ctc_merge_repeated=true, ignore_longer_outputs_than_inputs=false, preprocess_collapse_repeated=false](concat, labels, Select, logit_length)' with input shapes: [32,62,72], [?,2], [?], [32].

The key problem seems to be a mismatch between:

The logits (y_pred) produced by the model, with shape (batch_size=32, time_steps=62, num_classes=72).
The SparseTensor (labels) representing the ground-truth labels.
The input_lengths and label_lengths used for computing the loss.

Here’s what I know:

The input_lengths tensor should match the time steps of the model's output (62).
The label_lengths tensor should represent the number of valid characters in each label sequence and must not exceed input_lengths.

I’m working with a dataset of approximately 20,000 samples. Each sample consists of:

A cropped grayscale image of an ID card (500x80 pixels).
A corresponding .txt file containing the ground-truth text for the image.

What I’ve Tried

SparseTensor Construction: I’m converting the padded labels into a SparseTensor:

  indices = tf.where(padded_labels != -1)  # Non-padding indices
  values = tf.gather_nd(padded_labels, indices)
  dense_shape = tf.cast(tf.shape(padded_labels), tf.int64)

  sparse_labels = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(
                                indices=indices,
                                values=values,
                                dense_shape=dense_shape
                                                        )
  sparse_labels = tf.sparse.reorder(sparse_labels)



Clipping Label Lengths: Ensuring label_lengths does not exceed input_lengths:

label_lengths = tf.clip_by_value(label_lengths, 0, tf.reduce_max(input_lengths))



Matching Batch Sizes: Ensuring all tensors have the same batch size:

batch_size = tf.shape(y_pred)[0]
input_lengths = input_lengths[:batch_size]
label_lengths = label_lengths[:batch_size]
padded_labels = padded_labels[:batch_size]


Testing with Dummy Data: Verified tf.nn.ctc_loss works with mock data:

dummy_logits = tf.random.uniform((5, 10, 20), minval=-1, maxval=1)
dummy_labels = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(
    indices=[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]],
    values=[1, 2, 3],
    dense_shape=[5, 3]
)
dummy_input_lengths = tf.constant([10, 10, 10, 10, 10], dtype=tf.int32)
dummy_label_lengths = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 1, 1], dtype=tf.int32)

loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(
    labels=dummy_labels,
    logits=dummy_logits,
    label_length=dummy_label_lengths,
    logit_length=dummy_input_lengths,
    blank_index=-1
)
print("CTC Loss:", tf.reduce_mean(loss))


Relevant Code
Here’s the core part of the training step where the error occurs:
train.py

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from model import build_crnn
from data_loader import OCRDataset, split_dataset
from text_processor import TextProcessor
from config import (
    DATASET_PATH,
    BATCH_SIZE,
    IMAGE_HEIGHT,
    IMAGE_WIDTH,
    MAX_TEXT_LENGTH,
    EPOCHS,
    LEARNING_RATE,
)


def ctc_loss(y_true, y_pred, input_length, label_length):
    """
    Compute the CTC (Connectionist Temporal Classification) loss.

    Args:
        y_true: True labels (padded sequences).
        y_pred: Predicted logits (from CRNN model).
        input_length: Lengths of the input sequences.
        label_length: Lengths of the true label sequences.

    Returns:
        Tensor: CTC loss.
    """
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.ctc_loss(
            labels=y_true,
            logits=y_pred,
            label_length=label_length,
            logit_length=input_length,
            blank_index=-1,  # Use the last index in the character set for the blank token
        )
    )


def preprocess_batch(images, labels, text_processor):
    """
    Prepare a batch of images and labels for training.

    Args:
        images: Preprocessed images.
        labels: Text labels for the images.
        text_processor: TextProcessor instance for converting text to sequences.

    Returns:
        Tuple: Preprocessed images, padded labels, input lengths, and label lengths.
    """
    # Convert labels to integer sequences
    label_sequences = [
        text_processor.text_to_sequence(label) for label in labels if label
    ]
    label_padded = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
        label_sequences, maxlen=MAX_TEXT_LENGTH, padding="post", value=-1
    )

    # Compute input lengths dynamically based on the CRNN model's downsampling factor
    downsampling_factor = 8  # Adjust this if your model architecture changes
    input_lengths = tf.constant(
        [IMAGE_WIDTH // downsampling_factor] * len(label_sequences)
    )

    # Actual lengths of the labels
    label_lengths = tf.constant(
        [min(len(seq), MAX_TEXT_LENGTH) for seq in label_sequences]
    )

    # Ensure images have the correct shape
    images = tf.convert_to_tensor(images)
    if len(images.shape) == 3:  # Add channel dimension if missing
        images = tf.expand_dims(images, axis=-1)

    return images, label_padded, input_lengths, label_lengths


def extract_characters_from_labels(labels):
    """
    Extract all unique characters from the dataset's labels.

    Args:
        labels (list): List of text labels.

    Returns:
        str: String containing all unique characters.
    """
    unique_chars = set()
    for label in labels:
        if label:  # Ignore empty or None labels
            unique_chars.update(label)
    return "".join(sorted(unique_chars))


@tf.function
def custom_train_step(model, optimizer, inputs, padded_labels):
    """
    Perform a single custom training step.

    Args:
        model (tf.keras.Model): The CRNN model.
        optimizer (tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer): The optimizer.
        inputs (dict): A dictionary containing:
            - "image_input": Tensor of shape (batch_size, height, width, channels).
            - "input_length": Tensor of shape (batch_size,).
            - "label_length": Tensor of shape (batch_size,).
        padded_labels (tf.Tensor): Padded labels of shape (batch_size, max_label_length).

    Returns:
        float: Computed loss for the batch.
    """
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # Forward pass
        y_pred = model(inputs["image_input"], training=True)

        # Calculate input lengths and label lengths
        input_lengths = tf.fill([tf.shape(y_pred)[0]], tf.shape(y_pred)[1])  # Time steps
        label_lengths = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(padded_labels != -1, tf.int32), axis=1)  # Valid label lengths

        # Clip label lengths to match input lengths
        label_lengths = tf.clip_by_value(label_lengths, 0, tf.reduce_max(input_lengths))

        # Convert padded labels to SparseTensor
        indices = tf.where(padded_labels != -1)  # Get indices of valid (non-padding) labels
        values = tf.gather_nd(padded_labels, indices)  # Gather the valid label values
        dense_shape = tf.cast(tf.shape(padded_labels), tf.int64)  # Original dense shape
        sparse_labels = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(
            indices=indices,
            values=values,
            dense_shape=dense_shape
        )
        sparse_labels = tf.sparse.reorder(sparse_labels)

        # Debug: Print all tensors
        tf.print("y_pred shape:", tf.shape(y_pred))
        tf.print("Sparse Indices:", sparse_labels.indices)
        tf.print("Sparse Values:", sparse_labels.values)
        tf.print("Sparse Dense Shape:", sparse_labels.dense_shape)
        tf.print("Input Lengths:", input_lengths)
        tf.print("Label Lengths:", label_lengths)

        # Compute loss
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.ctc_loss(
                labels=sparse_labels,
                logits=y_pred,
                label_length=label_lengths,
                logit_length=input_lengths,
                blank_index=-1
            )
        )

    # Backward pass and optimization
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    return loss



def train():
    # Step 3: Split the dataset into train, validation, and test sets
    (train_paths, train_labels), (val_paths, val_labels), _ = split_dataset(
        DATASET_PATH, test_size=0.2, val_size=0.1
    )

    # Extract unique characters from training labels
    CHARACTERS = extract_characters_from_labels(train_labels)

    num_classes = len(CHARACTERS) + 1  # Add 1 for the CTC blank token
    print("Num Classes are:", num_classes)

    print(f"Extracted CHARACTERS: {CHARACTERS}")

    # Step 2: Initialize TextProcessor for label encoding/decoding
    text_processor = TextProcessor(CHARACTERS)

    # Step 4: Initialize OCRDataset for train and validation sets
    train_dataset = OCRDataset(train_paths, train_labels, BATCH_SIZE)
    val_dataset = OCRDataset(val_paths, val_labels, BATCH_SIZE)

    # Step 5: Create TensorFlow datasets for train and validation
    train_tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: (
            preprocess_batch(images, labels, text_processor)
            for images, labels in train_dataset
        ),
        output_signature=(
            tf.TensorSpec(
                shape=(BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1), dtype=tf.float32
            ),
            tf.TensorSpec(
                shape=(BATCH_SIZE, MAX_TEXT_LENGTH), dtype=tf.int32
            ),  # Fixed label padding length
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE,), dtype=tf.int32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE,), dtype=tf.int32),
        ),
    )

    val_tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: (
            preprocess_batch(images, labels, text_processor)
            for images, labels in val_dataset
        ),
        output_signature=(
            tf.TensorSpec(
                shape=(BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1), dtype=tf.float32
            ),
            tf.TensorSpec(
                shape=(BATCH_SIZE, MAX_TEXT_LENGTH), dtype=tf.int32
            ),  # Fixed label padding length
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE,), dtype=tf.int32),
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(BATCH_SIZE,), dtype=tf.int32),
        ),
    )

    # Step 6: Build the CRNN model
    crnn = build_crnn((IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1), num_classes)

    # Step 7: Define optimizer
    optimizer = Adam(LEARNING_RATE)

    # Step 8: Training loop
    print("Starting training...")
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}")
        for batch, (images, padded_labels, input_lengths, label_lengths) in enumerate(
            train_tf_dataset
        ):
            inputs = {
                "image_input": images,
                "input_length": input_lengths,
                "label_length": label_lengths,
            }
            loss = custom_train_step(crnn, optimizer, inputs, padded_labels)
            print(f"Batch {batch + 1}, Loss: {loss.numpy():.4f}")
            
        # Validation at the end of the epoch
        print("Validating...")
        val_loss = 0.0
        val_batches = 0
        for images, padded_labels, input_lengths, label_lengths in val_tf_dataset:
            inputs = {
                "image_input": images,
                "input_length": input_lengths,
                "label_length": label_lengths,
            }
            y_pred = crnn(inputs, training=False)
            val_loss += ctc_loss(
                padded_labels, y_pred, input_lengths, label_lengths
            ).numpy()
            val_batches += 1
        print(f"Validation Loss: {val_loss / val_batches:.4f}")

    # Optional: Save the trained model
    crnn.save("crnn_ocr_model.h5")
    print("Model saved to crnn_ocr_model.h5")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train()


model.py

from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model

def build_crnn(input_shape, num_classes):
    """
    Build the CRNN model for OCR tasks.

    Args:
        input_shape (tuple): Shape of input images (height, width, channels).
        num_classes (int): Number of unique characters in the dataset.
    
    Returns:
        keras.Model: Compiled CRNN model.
    """
    # Input layer
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name="image_input")

    # Convolutional layers for feature extraction
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    print(f"After MAX1: {x.shape}")

    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    print(f"After MAX2: {x.shape}")

    x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    print(f"After MAX3: {x.shape}")

    # Reshape for RNN layers
    # Collapse height and feature maps for sequence modeling
    x = layers.Reshape(target_shape=(x.shape[2], x.shape[1] * x.shape[3]))(x)   # Combine height and depth
    print(f"After Reshape: {x.shape}")

    # Recurrent layers for sequence modeling
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(x)
    print(f"After Bi1: {x.shape}")
    x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(x)
    print(f"After Bi2: {x.shape}")

    # Fully connected layer for classification
    outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax", name="dense_output")(x)
    print(f"final output: {outputs.shape}")
    # Define and return the model
    model = Model(inputs, outputs, name="CRNN")
    return model


data_loader.py
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from utils import preprocess_image
from config import *


def split_dataset(dataset_path, test_size=0.2, val_size=0.1):
    """
    Split the dataset into training, validation, and test sets.

    Args:
        dataset_path (str): Path to the dataset.
        test_size (float): Fraction of data for testing.
        val_size (float): Fraction of data for validation.

    Returns:
        tuple: Lists of file paths and corresponding labels for training, validation, and test sets.
    """
    image_paths = []
    labels = []

    # Iterate over dataset directory to collect image paths and labels
    for file_name in os.listdir(dataset_path):
        if file_name.endswith(".jpg"):
            image_paths.append(os.path.join(dataset_path, file_name))
            label_file = file_name.replace(".jpg", ".txt")
            label_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, label_file)
            if os.path.exists(label_path):
                with open(label_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    labels.append(f.read().strip())
            else:
                print(file_name)
                labels.append(None)  # Handle unlabeled images

    # Split into train and temp (validation + test)
    train_paths, temp_paths, train_labels, temp_labels = train_test_split(
        image_paths, labels, test_size=(test_size + val_size), random_state=42
    )

    # Further split temp into validation and test
    val_paths, test_paths, val_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(
        temp_paths,
        temp_labels,
        test_size=(test_size / (test_size + val_size)),
        random_state=42,
    )

    return (
        (train_paths, train_labels),
        (val_paths, val_labels),
        (test_paths, test_labels),
    )





class OCRDataset(Sequence):
    """
    Custom data loader for OCR tasks. Generates batches of preprocessed images and corresponding labels.
    """

    def __init__(self, image_paths, labels, batch_size):
        """
        Initialize the OCRDataset loader.

        Args:
            image_paths (list): List of image file paths.
            labels (list): List of corresponding text labels.
            batch_size (int): Number of samples per batch.
        """
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.labels = labels
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Get the number of batches per epoch.

        Returns:
            int: Number of batches.
        """
        return len(self.image_paths) // self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """
        Get a batch of data.

        Args:
            idx (int): Batch index.

        Returns:
            tuple: Tuple of (images, labels).
        """
        # Select paths and labels for the current batch
        batch_image_paths = self.image_paths[
            idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size
        ]
        batch_labels = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size : (idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        # Load and preprocess images
        images = [
            preprocess_image(img_path, (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH))
            for img_path in batch_image_paths
        ]

        # Convert to NumPy array
        images = np.array(images)

        return images, batch_labels



text_processor.py

class TextProcessor:
    """
    Handles text-to-sequence and sequence-to-text conversions.
    """

    def __init__(self, characters):
        """
        Initialize the TextProcessor with a character set.

        Args:
            characters (str): All possible characters in the dataset.
        """
        self.characters = characters
        self.char_to_num = {char: i for i, char in enumerate(characters)}
        self.num_to_char = {i: char for i, char in enumerate(characters)}

    def text_to_sequence(self, text):
        """
        Convert a text string to a sequence of integers.

        Args:
            text (str): Input text string.

        Returns:
            list: List of integers representing the text.
        """

        sequence = []
        for char in text:
            if char in self.char_to_num:
                index = self.char_to_num[char]
                sequence.append(index)
        return sequence

    def sequence_to_text(self, sequence):
        """
        Convert a sequence of integers back to text.

        Args:
            sequence (list): Sequence of integers.

        Returns:
            str: Decoded text string.
        """
        text = []
        for num in sequence:
            if num in self.num_to_char:
                text.append(self.num_to_char[num])

        return "".join(text)




config.py

IMAGE_WIDTH = 500  # Image width
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 80  # Image height
BATCH_SIZE = 32  # Batch size for training
MAX_TEXT_LENGTH = 77
NUM_CLASSES = 128
EPOCHS = 2
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4


Debug Outputs

y_pred shape: (32, 62, 72)
input_lengths: (32,)
label_lengths: (32,)
sparse_labels.dense_shape: (32, 77)



Questions

What could cause the mismatch between label_length and input_length during the CTC Loss computation?
How can I ensure that the SparseTensor and all length tensors (input_lengths, label_lengths) are correctly aligned?
Are there better ways to preprocess or structure the data to avoid this issue?
Any help or insights are greatly appreciated!

